# problems with column ordering in JQuery DataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I'm new to JQuery so please be patient.

I'm making a select that includes 5 options, including one to return all records.

```
<select id="sBusqueda" class="form-control fondo" name="sBusqueda" onchange="ModicaCampoTexto($(this));">
           <option value="all">Todos</option>
           <option value="nomProv">Nombre Proveedor</option>
           <option value="nSolicitud">Nº Solicitud</option>
</select>
```

At the moment everything works fine and if I select the "all" option within my view, it reloads the records correctly, but... in ascending order and what I need is that it returns the data from highest to lowest.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var tablaSolicitud = $('#TablaSolicitudes').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, 'desc']],
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "searching": false,
            //"ordering": false,
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("CargaSolicitudes", "DPSolicitudes")',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "DPSolicitudId", "name": "DPSolicitudId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "NumeroSolicitud", "name": "NumeroSolicitud", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "CentroCosto", "name": "CentroCosto", "autoWidth": true },             
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[5 ,10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100, 99999], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100, 'TODOS']],
        });


$('#sBusqueda').change(function () {
            var opcionSeleccionada = $(this).val();

            // Verificar si la opción seleccionada es "Todos"
            if (opcionSeleccionada === 'all') {

                // Esto funciona 
                // Here I need your help
                var tablaReload = $('#TablaSolicitudes').DataTable();
                tablaReload.order([[0, 'desc']]).draw();
            }
        });
```

I did not put the complete code because it would be very long, but the only thing I need is to know why it doesn't order the records from highest to lowest, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your DataTable is using `"serverSide": true`. This means that all paging, filtering, and sorting is delegated to your server. DataTables does not perform any of that logic for you.

Specifically, when you choose your `Todos` option, that causes the following line of code to be executed:

```
tablaReload.order([[0, 'desc']]).draw();
```

But that does not mean DataTables performs any sorting.

Instead...

1. The `order([[0, 'desc']])` sets the new sort order for the table.
2. The `draw()` automatically triggers a request to be sent to your server, using the DataTable's `ajax` option.
3. That request contains the new sort order. It's in the `POST` request body.

A fragment of that request body may look like this:

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "column": 0,
      "dir": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see the `order([[0, 'desc']])` has been added to the Ajax request's JSON.

It's up to your C# code to parse the request body, and then use this sorting instruction (along with the [other request fields](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters)) to provide the new page of results - in the requested sort order.

You haven't shown us any of your C# code. But that is where you need to look.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check the code in the controller